# import method can not read the excel file

Tags: .net, excel, file, model-view-controller, import

in my index view i write this code:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Import", "ItemDetails", FormMethod.Post, new { 
enctype="multipart/form-data"})) 
{ 
    @Html.Raw(ViewBag.Error); 
    <span>import from Excel :</span> 
    <input type="file" /> <input type="submit" value="import" class="btn btn- 
     primary"> 
}
```

so i uploaded an excel file and press on import button, the problem is that the code can not see the excel file, it sees that the excel file is null although i have been already uploaded it with extension xlsx

```
public ActionResult Import(HttpPostedFileBase excelFile)
{   
    if (excelFile == null || excelFile.ContentLength == 0 )
    {
        ViewBag.Error = "select excel file <br/>";
        return View("Index");
    }
    else
    {
        //if file is not null
        if (excelFile.FileName.EndsWith("xls") || 
          excelFile.FileName.EndsWith("xlsx"))
        {
            string path = Server.MapPath("~/Content" + 
               excelFile.FileName);
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
            {
                System.IO.File.Delete(path);

            }
            excelFile.SaveAs(path);
            Excel.Application application = new Excel.Application();

            Excel.Workbook workBook = 
            application.Workbooks.Open(path);
            Excel.Worksheet worksheet = workBook.ActiveSheet;
            Excel.Range range = worksheet.UsedRange;
            List<ItemDetails> itemDetails = new List<ItemDetails>();
            for (int x = 1; x < range.Rows.Count; x++)
            {
                ItemDetails i = new ItemDetails();
                i.Id = ((Excel.Range)range.Cells[x, 1]).Text;
                i.Factory = ((Excel.Range)range.Cells[x, 2]).Text;
                i.ItemCode = ((Excel.Range)range.Cells[x, 3]).Text;
                i.Description = ((Excel.Range)range.Cells[x,4]).Text;
                i.UnitMeasure = ((Excel.Range)range.Cells[x,5]).Text;
                i.Weight = ((Excel.Range)range.Cells[x, 6]).Text;
                itemDetails.Add(i);
            }
            ViewBag.itemDetails = itemDetails;
            return View("Success");
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.Error = "the file type is not correct<br/>";
            return View("Index");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to connect the posted file to your variable:

```
<input type="file" name="excelFile" />
```